# Finding the norm

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Show that the following functions are linear and  continuous  .then find the norm .

A)$
{f}{\mathrm{(}}{x}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{{=}}\frac{1}{{2}\mathrm{\varepsilon}}\left[{{x}{\mathrm{(}}\mathrm{\varepsilon}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{{+}}{x}{\mathrm{(}}\mathrm{{-}}\mathrm{\varepsilon}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{{-}}{2}{x}{\mathrm{(}}{0}{\mathrm{)}}}\right]{\mathrm{,}}\hspace{0.33em}\mathrm{\varepsilon}\mathrm{\in}\left[{\mathrm{{-}}{1}{\mathrm{,}}{1}}\right]\hspace{0.33em}{\mathrm{,}}\hspace{0.33em}{x}\mathrm{{=}}{x}{\mathrm{(}}{t}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{\in}{C}\left[{\mathrm{{-}}{1}{\mathrm{,}}{1}}\right]
$

B) $
{f}{\mathrm{(}}{x}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{{=}}{x}_{{1}\mathrm{{+}}}{x}_{{2}\hspace{0.33em}}\hspace{0.33em}{\mathrm{,}}{x}\mathrm{{=}}{\mathrm{(}}{x}_{1\mathrm{,}}{x}_{2}{\mathrm{,....)}}\mathrm{\in}{l}_{2}
$

I found a difficul in finding the norm especially .can you help me thanks in advance.

Comment: Why did you put every symbol in `\mathrm` braces?

Comment: Linearity is easy, and since you are working on Banach spaces, it is enough to show the norm is finite for continuity. So compute the norm.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг ok and soo my teacher calculated the two sides so I am  confused. Cause I can deal with one side of the inequality

Comment: Which side are you unable to deal with?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг can you help me for the second one really I stuck on it

Comment: For the second one, think about the following question: Given $x_1,x_2$ such that $x_1^2 + x_2^2 = 1$, what is the maximum value of $x_1 + x_2$? That value is the norm of $f(x)$. Since it is finite, $f$ will be continuous.